# Getting information about what road is at certain latitude and longitude

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1

I am using ArcGIS Desktop and I have a bunch of points that are part of a road network. I have created a shapefile using the starting and end point for each segment.

Is there a way to add a field to this data that corresponds to the road that it lies on?

Comment: In newer versions of ArcGIS you can use Spatial Join tool for this but I'm not sure that is available in 10.1, https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/spatial-join.htm

Comment: @artwork21 if not present since ArcGIS 8.0 (I think it may have been), I think Spatial Join was present many years before 10.1.

Comment: It was available 15 years before that in Arcview 3.